# From jpg to animated gif

Tags: image-processing, ffmpeg, imagemagick, jpeg, animated-gif

I'm desperate, I need to convert some jpg images into an animated gif.

I've tried ffmpeg, but the result has a terrible quality.

Also tried imagemagick, and the result looks great but it weights 511 KB !!

Anyone please can tell me what to use or how to use the before applications to get a final animated gif with a normal quality and a normal weight for a gif??

As I said I'm desperate, I need to finish this asap :(

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not looking too deeply into the details, this link might have what you are looking for: http://www.somethinkodd.com/oddthinking/2005/12/06/python-imaging-library-pil-and-animated-gifs/, in particular the first link in the comment by Almar on June 16, 2009.

This approach uses the Python and the Python Imaging Library. If you're not handy with either, then it sounds like this approach is going to take longer than you're hoping.

By the way, you might want to ask this question on superuser ... stackoverflow is for programming questions, superuser is more generally about 'doing stuff with computers'.

Answer (score 0):

FIJI or ImageJ do this pretty well.  See my answer to an identical SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230353/how-to-create-gif-animation-from-a-stack-of-jpgs/37193012#37193012).