# ImageJ API: how to change the framerate when writing AVI

Tags: java, avi, imagej

I would like to use the AVI_Writer from the ImageJ API in my java program.
However, even though I can automate the movie writing, I haven't found out how to change the framerate when using the method:

writeImage(ImagePlus imp, java.lang.String path, int compression, int jpegQuality)

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the menu command for [saving as AVI](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-26.html#sub%3aSaveAs%3EAvi...), it has an option to set the frame rate, which is taken from a setting hidden in [*Image > Stacks > Tools > Animation Options...*](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-28.html#sub%3aAnimation-Options...) in the menu.

Using the [command finder](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-31.html#sub%3aCommand-Finder), which you can invoke by typing [L], you find the sources for these two commands:

- File > Save As > AVI... => `ij.plugin.filter.AVI_Writer`
- Image > Stacks > Tools > Animation Options... => `ij.plugin.Animator("options")`

The command finder provides a handy button that directly links to the source files, have a look [here](http://fiji.sc/AVI_Writer.java) and [here](http://fiji.sc/Animator.java). You'll find that the frame rate setting is stored as `fps` in the [Calibration](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/index.html?ij/measure/Calibration.html) of the [ImagePlus](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/index.html?ij/ImagePlus.html).

Comment: Thank you, I had tried to create a new Calibration like this: Calibration cal=new Calibration(ip), where ip is my ImagePlus, but it hadn't worked. Instead, I did Calibration cal=ip.getCalibration(); cal.fps=60; ip.setCalibration(cal); and now it works perfectly :D